# How can I filter Django url?

Tags: django

I have two function in views.py, two different html page and two different url in urls.py :

My url :

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[\w\._-]+)/$', StudentDetailView.as_view(
    template_name="profile_student.html"), name='auth_profile_s'),

url(r'^profile/teacher/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', TeacherDetailView.as_view(
    template_name="profile_teacher.html"), name='auth_profile_t'),
```

Here is the problem :

Example :

Student1:

username = student1,  pk = 2

Teacher1 :

username = teacher1,  pk =2

In web browser when I write this url : 
    http://www.sitename.com/profile/student1/
I display student profile. But if I write this :
    http://www.sitename.com/profile/teacher1/
I can display teacher profile but in student html page.
I want to get an 404 error. How can I filter url ?

Comment: http://www.sitename.com/profile/teacher1/ doesn't match your teacher URL. Do you mean  http://www.sitename.com/profile/teacher/1/ ?

Comment: If I use a student username as an argument for teacher url, I display a teacher but in wrong html page. I shouldnt. I mean I want to get an error. Because student is not a teacher

Comment: You would need to share some more of your code to help with this, I think.

Comment: Please share the `get_queryset()` of these views and or some info about the Model(s)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify your `urls.py` like this:

```
url(r'^profile/student/(?P<username>[\w\._-]+)/$', StudentDetailView.as_view(
template_name="profile_student.html"), name='auth_profile_s'),
```